# Change hashing password algorith in Jasig CAS

Tags: ldap, openldap, password-policy, cas

I configurated my Jasig CAS to authenticate user from LDAP.
Now, I would to change my hashing  password algorith. Where, in CAS configuration, have I to configure it?

I use Jasig CAS 3.5.2 and OpenLDAP Server.

tnx

Answer (score 1):

Jasig CAS will attempt to bind to the LDAP server using the username (well, dn it constructs based on the username) and password data provided by the user.

Hashing will then be done by the LDAP server internally, which will also compare the hashes.

So in short: no reconfiguration of CAS is needed when changing the password hashing.